# createObjectURL() does not generate an appropriate image URL

Tags: javascript, blob, imageurl

I am using JavaScript to generate an image URL. When I opened the url generated, the image is just a small rectangle with black background, which is not the image I want at all. Hence, I am not sure where the problem is.

My response from the backend is:

> filename=imageName, imageData = base64Image, dataUrl =
>   "data:image/gif;base64," + base64Image

`str.split(':').pop().split(';')[0];` -> this line is equal to image/gif

```js
 axios.post('/convert/image', fd, {'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data'})
           .then (res => {
            // decoded = base64.decodebytes(res.data.imageData);
            // console.log(decoded);
            var encodedString = btoa(res.data.imageData);
            // console.log(encodedString);
            var decodedData = window.atob(encodedString);
            var byteNumbers = new Array(decodedData.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < decodedData.length; i++) {
              byteNumbers[i] = decodedData.charCodeAt(i);
            }
            var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
            var str = res.data.dataUrl;
            var type = str.split(':').pop().split(';')[0];
            var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(byteArray)], {type: type});
            console.log(blob);


            var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'),
            a = document.createElement('a');
            a.download = 'download';
            var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
          
            a.href = urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob);
            a.dataset.downloadurl = [type, a.download, a.href].join(':');
            
            console.log(a.dataset.downloadurl);
            e.initEvent('click', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
            a.dispatchEvent(e);


            urlCreator.revokeObjectURL(a.href);
      });
```

Comment: Your `dataUrl` is already a perfectly usable URL. Try opening it in your browser. You don't need to decode it and create a single-use URL

Comment: yeah, dataUrl is usable, but it has a limit on image size, so I cannot download an image with a big size.